# Doubt to interpret a probability question and its variations.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

1) A couple has two children and at least one of them is female. What is the probability of the second child also being a female ?

2) A couple has one child, a second child is coming, what is the probability of this second child being female ?

3) A couple has one child, what is the probability of this child being a female ?

What is the difference between the interpretation of the questions above ? 
Why is the birth of a person influenced the birth of another ? Shouldn't they be statistically independent ? What is the correct interpretation ? For me, intuitively, the answer for the probability of being a female or male is always 50%, independent of the above interpretation.

Extra:
4) What is the probability of a couple having two female children ? 
Now, for me, it is clear that the probability is 25%. What is the correct interpretation of the questions above ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is a conditional probability.  What is the probability that both children are girls, given that at least one of them is a girl.  You seem to be thinking that the question says something like, "The older one is a girl," but that's not correct.

The second is what you say. The probability is $\frac12$.

The third is the same.

For the fourth, I don't see how it can be answered as written.  We don't even know the probability that a couple has a least two children.  The answer you give $\frac14$ is correct, given that the couple has exactly two children, but the question doesn't say that.

**EDIT**

The OP points out correctly, that the second one is a conditional probability also.  However in that case, the second event is independent of the first.  The probability that the second child is a girl given that the first child is a girl is the same as the probability that the second child is a girl, which we assume to be $\frac12$.

In the first case, the condition really matters.  We have *a priori*, four equally likely possibilities: BB, BG, GB, GG, and the condition eliminates the first of these.

Comment: Why the first is considered as conditional probability and the second not ? I do not see much difference between them..

Comment: @ViniciusArruda I see what you mean.  I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you! [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy_or_Girl_paradox) link also helped me !